# Insert xml file into XMLTable using JDBC

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, xmltype

I have created a XMLType table in Oracle. I am trying to insert an XML file into the table using JDBC. It is throwing -

> `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BINARY`

The code is -

> ```
>        OraclePreparedStatement  statement = (OraclePreparedStatement) getConnection().prepareStatement
>        ("insert into person values(?)");
>        FileInputStream fileinp =  new FileInputStream(file);
>        statement.setBinaryStream(1, fileinp, fileLength);      
>        statement.executeUpdate();
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to insert binary data directly into your XMLType column, and there is no implicit casting for that. Assuming your file is actually text you can treat is as a CLOB rather than a BLOB:

```
OraclePreparedStatement statement =
  (OraclePreparedStatement) getConnection().prepareStatement(
    "insert into person values(xmltype(?))");
FileInputStream fileinp =  new FileInputStream(file);
InputStreamReader filerdr = new InputStreamReader(fileinp);
pStmt.setCharacterStream(1, filerdr, fileLength);
pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Note that the statement is now using `xmltype(?)` (although it works without that as there is implicit casting from CLOB, but I think it's better to be explicit anyway); and I'm using an `InputStreamReader` to pass the text in. You can, and probably should, use a buffered reader:

```
FileInputStream fileinp =  new FileInputStream(file);
InputStreamReader filerdr = new InputStreamReader(fileinp);
BufferedReader filebuf = new BufferedReader(filerdr);
pStmt.setCharacterStream(1, filebuf, fileLength);
pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Tested with an XMLType column in a normal table, and with an XMLType table.

Passing a text file with setBinaryStream confuses XMLType; with the same valid file, using `setBinaryStream()` gets error:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of '3'
```

There's probably a way around that, but I'm assuming your file is just text and won't be a problem as a CLOB.

Answer (score 1):

As I see in the official documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10790/xdb11jav.htm) you can insert an XMLType in Java in one of two ways:

- By CLOB or string binding
- By setObject() or setOPAQUE() using

I would read the file to a string and then use it to the insert query